# How to set a custom view's view controller to custom view controller?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

I've been transitioning  my programmatically-created user interface over to interface builder, but I'm still fairly new to IB. I have a custom view inside of my main view (in the IB .xib file), which I want to link to its own view class, and, more importantly, its own view controller.

I know that traditionally, one references the custom view class from the IB property, and then uses -awakeFromNib in the custom view class to set up the view programatically.

However, I can't figure out how to reference the custom view *controller* class. How to I tell my custom view what it's controller should be? And is there a way to instantiate a view controller from IB, or should I be doing it from -awakeFromNib?

Advice would be appreciated :)
Obj-C please!

Comment: You're thinking a bit in reverse of standard usage.  Usually you create the controller, choose a way to display it, and it brings its views along with it...ones you have defined as belonging to it.  The view would seldom know about the controller explicitly.  It sounds as if you may be looking to have portions of the screen handled by different controllers.  If that's true, look at examples for container view controllers.

Comment: Right. But the view is created in IB as part of my main window, which has its own window controller, so in this case, the view exists before the controller. The custom view is actually inside a NSTableCellView, so that it will be reused multiple times over, are container view controller still the best idea in that case?